# Null error on AutoIncrement ID Column when inserting (using MDB linked to MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, ms-access

I created an MDB database and linked the tables to MySQL.

When I try to insert I get the following error:

> „FotoID” cannot be null

Stack Trace Error:

> Source:      System.Data Stack Trace: 
>   System.Data.DataColumn.CheckNullable(DataRow row)
>       System.Data.DataColumn.CheckColumnConstraint(DataRow row, DataRowAction action)
>       System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
>       System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Int32
>   position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
>       System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)
>       System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(DataRow row) ...

My C# code is the following:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM SFoto where SID="+sid;
cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

OleDbDataAdapter t2DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
OleDbCommandBuilder t2Command = new OleDbCommandBuilder(t2DataAdapter);
t2DataAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "SFoto");

row2 = ds.Tables["SFoto"].NewRow();
row2["FotoName"] = Path.GetFileName(foldername).ToString();
row2["FotoNote"] = megjtxt.Text;
row2["SID"] = sid; 
row2["FotoDefault"] = "true";
row2["InsertDate"] = utils.Settings.GetInsModDate() ;
row2["InsertedBy"] = utils.Settings.LoggedInUser;
ds.Tables["SFoto"].Rows.Add(row2);

t2DataAdapter.Update(ds, "SFoto");
```

The Table in MySQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE `sfoto` (
  `FotoID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FotoName` longtext,
  `FotoNote` longtext,
  `SID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FotoDefault` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifyDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `SID` (`SID`),
  KEY `FotoID` (`FotoID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I also created a trigger, but it didn't helped:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sfoto_before_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `sfoto`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET SESSION sql_mode='';

        SELECT `auto_increment` INTO @NEXTID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'sfoto';

        INSERT INTO sirfoto (`FotoID`,`FotoName`,`FotoNote`,`SID`,`FotoDefault`,`InsertDate`,`ModifyDate`,`InsertedBy`,`ModifiedBy`)
        VALUES(NULL,NEW.FotoName,NEW.FotoNote,NEW.SID,NEW.FotoDefault,NEW.InsertDate,NEW.ModifyDate,NEW.InsertedBy,NEW.ModifiedBy);
     /*   SET NEW.`FotoID` = @NEXTID;*/
END
```

Edit: I followed this video to create the linked tables to MySQL : [Linked Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js7U7esbrsY)

Comment: you are not selecting the `FotoID` column and updating..

Comment: @vivek nuna -  if I add `row2["FotoID"]= ` what value should I add to work? (This code worked with MDB. I decided to go with linked tables because the size of the MDB is limited to 2GB.)